# Vibrate without sound in ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Is there any way i can vibrate iphone without playing a sound?
So far i have been able to vibrate using sound only. I have tried following but both play sound with vibration

```
SystemSound.Vibrate.PlayAlertSound ();
SystemSound.Vibrate.PlaySystemSound();
```

Please advise

Answer (score 4):

From [monotouch-samples](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/SysSound/SysSoundViewControllerController.cs) this should work:

```
SystemSound.Vibrate.PlaySystemSound();
```

Maybe you changed your iPhone Vibration Sound Settings

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h> 

//Vibrate iphone 
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```